# Windows 8.1 takes 10 seconds to open file explorer from taskbar (not from start menu)

Tags: performance, windows-explorer, windows-8.1, delay

I open "This PC", and right click to to "Pin this program to taskbar". Now there's a shortcut to explorer in my taskbar, but when i click it, it takes around 10 seconds before the explorer window is showing.

If i click "This PC" in my start menu (3rd party software) it opens immediately.

Does anyone know why it's so slow to open when i use the shortcut in the taskbar?

Comment: What happens if you uninstall the 3rd party software?

Comment: Did you looked at this question?: http://superuser.com/questions/681895/windows-8-1-file-explorer-is-super-slow?rq=1

Comment: run ProcMon in background while starting Explorer. Now close Explorer and run it from Startmenu. Stop the ProcMon log and compare both starts to see the difference. http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-3-Process-Monitor, http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-4-Process-Monitor

Comment: why do you have a third party software to emulate the start menu?

Answer (score 0):

You should possibly try restarting your explorer, like this: press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd>, select Explorer in the list and click Restart.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this fix:

> 1. Go to `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar`, where the taskbar shortcuts are stored. (The IE team developed the idea, hence the path)
> 2. Right click on File Explorer, and click properties.
> 3. Change the path to `C:\Windows\explorer.exe`.

Source - [PokeOracle](http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/1139638-file-explorer-slow-to-open-from-taskbar/page-2#entry595743996)

Answer (score 0):

My guess you have a network mapped drive, or a energy efficient hard disk drive that needs to spin up in its firmware before reporting that its active to the file manager.